# g++ generated Assembly looks ugly

Tags: c++, assembly, g++

I'm quite familiar with gcc assembly... Recently I was forced to use g++ for some code cleanup. Let me mention I'm very familiar with assembly, hence out of curiosity I often take a look at how good the compiler generated asm is.

But the naming conventions with g++ are just bizarre. I was wondering if there are any guidelines on how to read its asm output ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: related: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Answer (score 26):

I don't find g++'s asm 'ugly' or hard to understand, though I've been working with GCC for over 8 years now.

On Linux, function labels usually go by _ZN, The "_ZN" prefix being a token that designates C++ name mangling (as opposed to C), followed by namespace the function belongs, then function names and argument types, then templates, if any.

Example:

```
    // tests::vec4::testEquality()
    _ZN5tests4vec412testEqualityEv

    _ZN - C++ mangling, 'N' for member (_ZZ for const or others)
    5tests - length (5 chars) + name
    4vec4 -length (4 chars) + sub namespace
    12testEquality - length (12 chars) + function name
    Ev - void argument (none)
```

Comment: Based on your example, I have to agree with Sam, that's ugly! They call it name "Mangling" for a reason! Although, you did provide the best answer so far.

Comment: I think "ID" in your example is the length of the next argument.  _ZN, 5 "tests", 4 "vec4", 12 "testEquality", E, v.

Comment: I think output of g++ generated assembly is ugly. it makes harder to understand.

Answer (score 20):

From *`man g++`*:

> **-fverbose-asm** 
>      Put extra commentary information in the generated assembly code to make it more 
>      readable. This option is generally only of use to those who actually need to read the 
>      generated assembly code (perhaps while debugging the compiler itself).

Comment: Dislamer: not as 'verbose' as you think.

Comment: LiraNuna is right.  It doesn't make it more readable, to me at least.  It doesn't demangle labels for you, which is what the OP seems to want.

Comment: no, it's pretty. You are freed from guessing where variable , what you are searching for, is located in the stack - name of variables are superscribed from the left side. Much simpler

Answer (score 14):

If you're looking at the naming convention for external symbols then this will follow the name mangling convention of the platform that you are using. It can be reversed with the `c++filt` program which will give you the human readable version of C++ function names, although they will (in all probability) no longer be valid linker symbols.

If you're just looking at local function labels, then you're out of luck. `g++`'s assembler output is for talking to the assembler and not really designed for ease of human comprehension. It's going to generate a set of relatively meaningless labels.

Answer (score 5):

If the code has debugging information, `objdump` can provide a more helpful disassembly :

```
-S, --source             Intermix source code with disassembly
-l, --line-numbers             Include line numbers and filenames in output
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who are working on demangling those names inside the program (like me), hopefully [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526814/6320608) helps.

```
def demangle(name):
    import subprocess as sp
    stdout, _ = sp.Popen(['c++filt', name], 
                         stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE).communicate()
    return stdout.split("\n")[0]

print demangle('_ZNSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE17_M_stringbuf_initESt13_Ios_Openmode')
```

Comment: Is that function for use within GDB or something?  GDB / objdump already have an option to demangle when disassembling: `objdump -C`.  I usually use `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  But anyway, if you have g++-generated asm, I think you can just pipe it through `c++filt`.

Comment: @PeterCordes The function is written in Python because in my case I am writing a parser that needs to understand the function names of C++.