# java library for C++ name mangling/demangling?

Tags: java, name-mangling

(similar to this question: [C++ Name Mangling Library for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526500/c-name-mangling-library-for-python))

I'm trying to experiment with some static analysis tools in Java that operate on C++ disassembly. I know there's "c++filt", but I'd like to avoid interfacing with an external program, and also c++filt only does *demangling*, whereas I'd like to do both mangling and demangling.

Is there a Java library that would have methods similar to this:

```
interface CMethod
{
    String getName();
    String getClassName();
    List<String> getArguments();
    String getReturnType();
}

interface Mangler
{
    CMethod demangle(String mangledName);
    String mangle(CMethod method);        
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that name mangling is entirely implementation dependent? It may change drastically, depending even on the target *ABI*.

Comment: yes, that's why I declared Mangler as an interface, presumably with several implementations